# How do we set column as foreign key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How do we set column as foreign key in Entity Framework in code first approach.
They way I am doing this is, it is not set as expected .--thanks

Comment: Can you post some code to illustrate the problem you're having? What have you tried and what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In referencing this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

In addition to navigation properties, we recommend that you include foreign key properties on the types that represent dependent objects. Any property with the same data type as the principal primary key property and with a name that follows one of the following formats represents a foreign key for the relationship: <navigation property name><principal primary key property name>, <principal class name><primary key property name>, or <principal primary key property name>.

For example, DepartmentID in the following example is a foreign key:

```
public class Department
{
    // Primary key
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    // Navigation property 
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } 
} 

public class Course 
{
    // Primary key 
    public int CourseID { get; set; } 

    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public int Credits { get; set; } 

    // Foreign key 
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 

    // Navigation properties 
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; } 
}
```